# Ordering by an Enum attribute

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5

I'm using an Enum property called flags with EF5. One of these flags is a 'sticky' flag. I have a list of items which I want to order by date, but I want all the stickies at the top. Is there any way to retrieve all stickies first, ordered by date, then all the rest, ordered by date?

My enum declaration is:

```
[Flags]
public enum ForumTopicFlags : int
{
    None = 0,
    Sticky = 1,
    Spam = 2,
    Deleted = 4,
    Locked = 8
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just order on Sticky, then by Date and you're done? Especially if the Enum only has two values?

Comment: Sticky is a flag value for an enum property.

Comment: Isn't that flag value an integer underneath? What are the distinct values in the database for that column? Or is it a bit mask?

Comment: I've updated the post with my enum declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, really:

```
var result = myList
     .OrderByDescending(x => (x.Flags & ForumTopicFlags.Sticky) != 0)
     .ThenBy(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: This statement needs some parenthesis; `.OrderByDescending(x => (x.Flags & ForumTopicFlags.Sticky) != 0)` but other than that it's brilliant.